# How to make XScreenSaver work on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, xscreensaver

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 (normal and minimum) on VirtualBox, and installed `gcc`, `libx11-dev`, `libxss-dev`. 
Then I compiled the code using `gcc -o idle idle.c -lXss -lX11`. When I run `./idle, I receive the error` No XSS available: event=0 error=0 errno=11`. It works on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, and 20.04.

My code:

```c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>
 
 #include <X11/Xlib.h>
 #include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
 
 int main(void)
 {
     Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
     if (!display) {
         printf("no display\n");
         return 1;
     }
     static XScreenSaverInfo *mit_info = NULL;
     int event_base, error_base;
     if (XScreenSaverQueryExtension(display, &event_base, &error_base))
     {
             mit_info = XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
             XScreenSaverQueryInfo(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), mit_info);
             printf("Idle Time: %li\n", mit_info->idle);
     } else {
             printf("No XSS available: event=%d error=%d errno=%d\n", event_base, error_base, errno);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 runs with Wayland instead of X11 by default. X software doesn't work on wayland. You may want to run X11 instead.

Comment: Thank you. After switching to X11, it works.